# Unable to call C++ function on mouse clicked in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing an application in QT using C++ and QML to replicate the gauges on a vehicle. My aim is to invoke a c++ function everytime the mouse is clicked in the mouse area. I googled and tried a lot of things, but am still not able to invoke my C++ function on mouse clicked. Since I am new to QT, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help resolve this.

**Gauge.pro file** :

```
folder_01.SOURCES = qml/testlib
folder_01.TARGET = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += static

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    rotationThread.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

QT += declarative

HEADERS += \
    rotationThread.h
```

**rotationThread.h file**

```
#ifndef ROTATIONTHREAD_H
#define ROTATIONTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class rotationThread : public QThread, public QObject
{
private:
    QObject *rootObject, *leftNeedleObj, *rightGaugeObj, *unacHeadObj, *mouseAreaObj;
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    Q_INVOKABLE void run();
public:
    rotationThread(QObject *pobj);
};

#endif // ROTATIONTHREAD_H
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariantAnimation>
#include <windows.h>
#include <QThread>
#include <rotationThread.h>
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    //Get access to the root objects
    QObject *rootObject = (QObject *)engine.rootObjects().front();
    //QObject *mouseAreaObj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("mouseArea");
    rotationThread rot(rootObject);
    qmlRegisterType<rotationThread(rot)>("testlib", 1, 0, "rotationThread");

    //QEvent *event;
    //QMouseEvent *event;

   // QObject::connect(mouseAreaObj, SIGNAL(clicked), qGuiApp, SLOT(rot.start()));

    /*if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
    rot.start();
    }*/

    return app.exec();
}
```

**rotationThread.cpp**

```
#include "rotationThread.h"
#include <QVariant>
#include <QtMath>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QMouseEvent>

rotationThread::rotationThread(QObject *pobj)
{
    rootObject = pobj;
}

void rotationThread::run()
{
    leftNeedleObj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("leftNeedle");
    rightGaugeObj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("rightGauge");
    unacHeadObj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("unacHead");
    mouseAreaObj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("mouseArea");

    QVariant angle=0, dummyX=0, dummyY=0;
    qreal x=0, y=0, div=0, calcAng=0;
    QPoint pos;

    dummyX = mouseAreaObj->property("x");
    dummyY = mouseAreaObj->property("y");

    x = dummyX.toReal();
    y = dummyY.toReal();

    /*QMouseEvent *clicked;
    if(clicked->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {*/

    //pos = QCursor::pos();
    //x = pos.x();
    //y = pos.y();

    div = (y/x);

    //At Origin
    if((x==0) && (y==0) )
    {
        angle = 0;
    }

    //At first quadrant
    if((x>0) && (y>0) )
    {
        calcAng = qAtan(div);
        angle = calcAng;
    }

    //At second quadrant
    if((x<0) && (y>0) )
    {
        calcAng = qAtan(div);
        calcAng = -(90 + calcAng);
        angle = calcAng;
    }

    //At third quadrant
    if((x<0) && (y<0) )
    {
        calcAng = qAtan(div);
        calcAng = -(calcAng - 90);
        angle = calcAng;
    }

    //At fourth quadrant
    if((x>0) && (y<0) )
    {
        calcAng = qAtan(div);
        calcAng = -(calcAng - 90);
        angle = calcAng;
    }

    QThread::msleep(100);
    leftNeedleObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
    rightGaugeObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
    unacHeadObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);

    /*//Rotating Clockwise
    while(angle<=360)
    {
        QThread::msleep(100);
        leftNeedleObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        rightGaugeObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        unacHeadObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        angle = angle.toInt() + 5;
    }*/

    QThread::msleep(100);
    angle=0;
    //}

    //Rotating Anticlockwise
    /*angle=0;
    while(angle>=(-360))
    {
        QThread::msleep(100);
        leftNeedleObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        rightGaugeObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        unacHeadObj->setProperty("stepRot", angle);
        angle = angle.toInt() - 5;
    }
    angle=0;*/
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import testlib 1.0

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    objectName: "mainWindow"
    width: 800
    height: 800
    color: "#000000"
    visible: true

    rotationThread{
        id: thread
        objectName: "thread"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: gaugeRec
        objectName: "gaugeRec"
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 800
        height: 361
        color: "#000000"
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#000000"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#000000"
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: leftGauge
            objectName: "leftGauge"
            x: 32
            y: 29
            width: 290
            height: 290
            source: "leftGauge.png"

            Image {
                id: leftNeedle
                objectName: "leftNeedle"
                property real stepRot: 0
                rotation: 0
                x: 100
                y: 100
                width: 90
                height: 90
                source: "leftNeedle.png"
                transform:
                    Rotation { origin.x: 45; origin.y: 45; angle: leftNeedle.stepRot}
                smooth: true
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: rightGauge
            objectName: "rightGauge"
            property real stepRot: 0
            x: 471
            y: 31
            width: 290
            height: 290
            source: "rightGauge.png"
            transform:
                Rotation { origin.x: 145; origin.y: 145; angle: rightGauge.stepRot }
            smooth: true
        }

        Image {
            id: rightNeedle
            objectName: "rightNeedle"
            x: 571
            y: 131
            width: 90
            height: 90
            source: "rightNeedle.png"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: headRec
        objectName: "headRec"
        x: 48
        y: 386
        width: 709
        height: 394
        color: "#000000"
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#000000"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#000000"
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: railTrack
            objectName: "railTrack"
            x: 279
            y: 100
            width: 154
            height: 294
            source: "railTrack.png"

            Image {
                id: unacHead
                objectName: "unacHead"
                property real stepRot: 0
                x: 63
                y: -165
                width: 26
                height: 328
                visible: true
                source: "unacHead.png"
                transform:
                    Rotation { origin.x: 13; origin.y: 164; angle: unacHead.stepRot }
                smooth: true
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        objectName: "mouseArea"
        x : 0
        y : 0
        width: 800
        height: 800
        hoverEnabled: false
        visible: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
        onClicked: { thread.run(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please let me know if it is possible to get the x,y coordinates of mouse clicked, with respect to an origin we set.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what you exactly want with your class (QThread, QObject...), but try this to invoke a c++ function from qml.

**myobject.cpp**

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QDebug>
MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void MyObject::myFunction(double mouseX, double mouseY)
{
    qDebug() << "My cpp function" << mouseX << mouseY;
}
```

**myobject.h**

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void myFunction(double mouseX, double mouseY);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "myobject.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    MyObject myObject;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", &myObject);


    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 100
    height: 100
    visible: true

MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      myObject.myFunction(mouseArea.mouseX, mouseArea.mouseY);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Read this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Comment: Thanks :), I'll try it out and let you know the outcome. But, I would still love to learn if it is possible to start a thread from QML. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Schoeffi,     I tried it, and it work great :).Thank you so much. If possible, let me know your thoughts on how to get the x,y coordinates of mouse clicked, with respect to an origin we set.   Best, Sam

Comment: Add paramters to your function and pass your coordinates from qml. (see my edit)